# C++ Exceptions: Why use or extend std::exception?

Tags: c++, exception

According to [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) it is perfectly usable to throw a string or integer. I find this to be pretty clean and easy to understand. What are the downsides to `throw "description of what happened"` rather than `throw std::runtime_error("description of what happened")`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That site is stupid, and teaches bad design.

If you throw `int` or `char*`, then you will have to catch it using `int` or `char*` only. You may qualify it with `const`.

If you throw `std::runtime_error`, then you can catch it using `std::runtime_error const &`, or its base class `std::exception const &`.

So what is good about it?

The good about it is that if you throw an exception using a class which is ultimately derived from `std::exception`, then you can write just ONE `catch` block which accepts the exception as `std::exception const&`, irrespective of [which *derived* class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) is used to throw exception.

Here is one example:

```
void f(A & a)
{
    if ( !check_arg(a) )
    {
          throw std::invalid_argument("invalid argument");
    }
    else if ( !check_size(a) )
    {
          throw std::length_error("invalid length");            
    }

    //code
    if(someCondition)
    {
          //assume your_own_defined_exception's ultimate base is std::exception
          throw your_own_defined_exception("condition unsatisfied");                         
    }
    //...

}
```

Now the interesting part:

```
try
{
      f(a); //it can throw exception of at least 3 types!
}
catch(std::exception const &e) //all types can be caught by just one catch!
{
     //handle this case
}
```

The good is that you are not *required* to write **three** `catch` blocks just because `f()` could throw **three** different types of exception. You *may* write more than one `catch` to handle them differently if that benefits you in some way. But the point to be noted here is:  that is **not** a requirement!

In short, you can take advantage of the class hierarchy.

Comment: So basically it naturally allows inheritance to simplify the design of error handling. Quite elegant. If I define my own exception class and do it that way, I can produce the same results, yes?

Comment: @StevenLu If you derive your own exception class, then you reinvent the wheel, and potentially break code that depends on catching std::exception.  While this may be fine for your personal projects, it makes your code hard to distribute to others.  The standard approach is to have an application-specific exception hierarchy that subclasses `std::exception`.  For example, have all of your exceptions be subclasses of `StevenLuException`, which is a subclass of `std::exception`.

Comment: @StevenLu: If your exception class derives ultimately from `std::exception`, then yes that is an elegant design. See the *third* exception called `your_own_defined_exception` in my example code. I said it has to be derived from `std::exception` ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

If you make it a rule in your code to throw exceptions only derived from std::exception then catching them is easier. In other words you can just have a single catch clause on std::exception:

```
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    log_message(e);
    throw;
}
```

But if you don't follow this rule then you end up having to write catch clauses when you don't have to.

Comment: there is little benefit to catch and rethrow at every layer, only use a `catch` clause if you really have something to do (and in C++, with RAII, this should be rare enough) or to "swallow" it.

Comment: I find it useful for generating a stack trace for exceptions that are not expected. It helps diagnosing an error and tracking where the exception orginated from.

Comment: I agree that stacks are useful, however there are two downsides to your approach. First it clutters the code, it's no longer obvious when a *specific* action is to be taken in case of exception. Second it's a performance hog, because the Zero Cost exception implementation that is used by popular compilers such as gcc or Clang places a harsh penalty on throws. There are other, and I find better, alternatives. Platform specific code to capture the stack at the point of throw is one; another is to use RAII to log "notes" that are added to the exception during unwinding.

Comment: (damned short notes)... also, related to performance, because try/catch generates heavyweight code, this might prevent inlining and reduce the potential gain of compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly because when you work with other people you have to agree upon what to catch. If I try catch a `const std::exception&` and you throw `const char*`, then I'm not going to catch your stuff and bad things could happen.

It doesn't really matter what type gets thrown and caught, as long as everyone sticks to it. I guess `std::exception` is chosen over `const char*` because it allows you to put more than just a string into the exception object. It's just more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

One additional point from he other answers is this -

If you throw an int or a string and you want to catch *one* specific error you can't.
You have to catch all "int" exceptions and then compare the ones you want to catch, and then rethrow any you are not prepared to deal with. If you inherit from exception you can catch the specific exception you want to handle and still have the advantage that you can just catch std::exception if you want to handle them all.